# How to add the current section name to the top?

Tags: header-footer

I'm trying to get the current section name and to add it to the header at right.

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
\renewcommand\chaptername{Chapitre}
\renewcommand\appendixname{Annexe}

\let\@oldmakechapterhead\@makechapterhead
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{10\p@}%
{\parindent \z@
{\reset@font
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}
\LARGE\@chapapp~\thechapter\par\nobreak}%
\par\nobreak
\vspace*{30\p@}
\interlinepenalty\@M
\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{b}{n}
{\raggedright \Huge #1}%
\par\nobreak
\vskip 20\p@
\hrule height 1pt
\par\nobreak
\vskip 45\p@
}}
\rhead{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

\chapter{ABC}

\end{document}
```

How do I to get the current section name and to put it into that line without adding it to TOC, TO Tables and TO Figures, please?

Comment: Can you describe a bit better what you want to have?  Do you just want a header on each page that carries the current section name?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly, you are trying to add a header on content pages without adding the same header to the TOC, LOT, LOF pages.

This is best accomplished with the `fancyhdr` package, which will make regular pages have a header that you define, while keeping frontmatter pages and other special pages (like first pages of Chapters, for instance) as "plain" style, which simply has a page number at the bottom.

This code gives just that:

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext} % For example

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} % Clear the headers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Width of line at top of page
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape\leftmark} % Mark right [R] of page with Chapter name [\leftmark]

\pagestyle{fancy} % Set default style for all content pages (not TOC, etc)

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%\chapter{ABC}
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: page1]

[image: page2]

[image: page3]

Comment: I'm trying to display the section of the current page at header's right side in fact. The problem is that when I try to write this `\rhead{\nouppercase\rightmark}` (I'm using a customized chapter's style), I get the section's name like you but it's also included on top of the TOC's page.

Comment: Can you add your custom chapter style to your question?  This is probably changing something that allows the header to continue on the first page of a chapter.

Comment: I've updated my posted code.

Comment: I would try adding `\thispagestyle{empty}%` just after `\def\@makechapterhead#1{%`.  This should make a completely blank page on each page affected by the custom chapter heading.

Comment: Please also note that your example code no longer compiles. It is very helpful to have full, working code that demonstrates the issue you have (so you should include everything needed to get to the point of having the header on every page including the TOC, etc... but nothing more).